# clicking checkboxes generated by angular-schema-form cause the error 'cannot read property 'length' of undefined'

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

I have the following schema and form declared in my controller:

```
$scope.schema = {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "s4_0": {
                "type": "array",
                "title": "CHECKBOXES",
                "items": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        1,
                        2,
                        3
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.form = [
        {
            "key": "s4_0",
            "type": "checkboxes",
            "titleMap": [
                {
                    "value": "1",
                    "name": "box 1"
                },
                {
                    "value": "2",
                    "name": "box 3"
                },
                {
                    "value": "3",
                    "name": "box 2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "submit",
            "title": "Submit"
        }
    ];
```

My view has the following form declaration:

```
<form name="myForm"
          sf-schema="schema"
          sf-form="form"
          ng-submit="onSubmit(myForm)"></form>
```

This renders the checkboxes correctly but every time i click on a checkbox, I get the following error:

```
angular.js:13424 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at schema-form.min.js:1
at $watchCollectionAction (angular.js:16734)
at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16869)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17133)
at $$debounceViewValueCommit (angular.js:26702)
at $setViewValue (angular.js:26674)
at HTMLInputElement.listener (angular.js:23277)
at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3)
at HTMLInputElement.r.handle (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3)
```

When i paste my schema and form into the angular-schema-form playground this works fine but in my app it keeps throwing an error. Also when submitted the value of the field gets saved as "false" instead of the array of options chosen.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

I would be happy to post more information that could be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused because i was not setting a model to my angular schema form. So add a model object to your scope and add sf-model in your form declaration to point to that variable:

```
$scope.surveymodel = {};

<form name="myForm"
          sf-schema="schema"
          sf-form="form"
          sf-model="surveymodel"
          ng-submit="onSubmit(myForm)"></form>
```